# How make support cyrillic letters in JavaCC?

Tags: character-encoding, internationalization, javacc

Can I make cyrillic tokens for *.jjt file?

For exampe tokens are given in jjt:

```
TOKEN : /* LITERALS */
{
    < TEST: "тест" >
|   < DEVELOP: "разработка" >
}
```

but the tokens in jj file look terrible:

```
TOKEN : /* LITERALS */
{
    < TEST: "\u0421\u201a\u0420\u00b5\u0421\u0403\u0421\u201a" >
|   < DEVELOP: "\u0421\u0402\u0420\u00b0\u0420\u00b7\u0421\u0402\u0420\u00b0\u0420\u00b1\u0420\u0455\u0421\u201a\u0420\u0454\u0420\u00b0" >
}
```

Use the following options:

```
options {
  JDK_VERSION = "1.6";
  UNICODE_INPUT = true;
  JAVA_UNICODE_ESCAPE = false;
  TRACK_TOKENS=true;
  STATIC=false;
}
```

If I do Unicode with the help of her class:

```
class GetUnicode {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      if (args.length < 1) return;
      for (String input: args) {
        for (int index = 0; index < input.length(); ++index) {
            final char c = input.charAt(index); 
            final String s = String.format ("\\u%04x", (int)c);
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
  }
}
```

After the start of the program:

```
$ java GetUnicode тест разработка                                                                                                                                                                                       
\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442
\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0430
```

As a result, I can see that the unicode strings do not match.
For example:

```
"\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442" != "\u0421\u201a\u0420\u00b5\u0421\u0403\u0421\u201a"
```

Do you have ideas why this happens?

PS: This bug occurs only under Windows OS.

Comment: Is this a question, or did you answer yourself after: _"Use the following options: ..."_?

Answer (score 1):

The .jj file has been generated with the cyrillic characters escaped (Unicode). This is a good thing since they can then not be misread by using the wrong encoding. You should not worry about it; the token manager will work just fine.

Comment: @Nicolay Moskvin Can you be more precise? What do you mean by "awful"?

Comment: Because unicode for word "тест" must be a value  "\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442" instead of "\u0421\u201a\u0420\u00b5\u0421\u0403\u0421\u201a"

Comment: @Nicolay Moskvin Then it means that JJTree reads your .jjt file using the wrong encoding. Unfortunately, the documentation at http://javacc.java.net/doc/JJTree.html doesn't mention any option to specify the encoding of the .jjt file. You have two options: use unicode escapes in your .jjt file (I know, it sucks) or modify the source of JJTree to force it to use the same encoding as your .jjt file.